# Avoid the termination of an applicaiton due to an exception generated by a thread

Tags: java, sockets, exception, java-threads

I'm working on a Client - Server application with Java Sockets.

The client must wait for a response from the server. When the server receives the client's request, it performs certain tasks to obtain a result that must be passed to the client - but performing these tasks could cause an error.

Is there any way in which when this error occurs the application does not terminate and can continue processing requests?

```
package Socket;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Server  
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        MainWindow application=new MainWindow();

        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);         
    }   
}

class MainWindow extends JFrame implements Runnable
{

    public MainWindow()
    {       
        setBounds(1200,300,280,350);                

        JPanel myPanel= new JPanel();

        myPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        text=new JTextArea();

        myPanel.add(text,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(myPanel);

        setVisible(true);

        Thread t= new Thread(this);

        t.start();      
    }

    private JTextArea text;

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        try 
        {
            ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket(9999);

            while(true)
            {
                Socket mySocket = Server.accept();

                DataInputStream input_stream = new DataInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());

                String message  = input_stream.readUTF();

                someMethod();           //This method can generate an exception, then the application closes and I can not receive new requests

                text.append("\n" + message);

                mySocket.close();
            }                        
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean like a try-catch?

Comment: What kind of exception? An IOException? Yes? You already catch them. Some runtime exeption? Catch the runtime exception too.

Comment: Yes, something like that

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I see, I'll try. Thanks

Comment: You might want to add a `finally` to actually close your sockets at the end there.

Comment: It doesn't end the application. It ends the thread, Unles you've caught it, and the compiler forces you to catch most of them. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catch the exception inside the loop.

```
ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket(9999);

while(true) {
   try {
       Socket mySocket = Server.accept();
       DataInputStream input_stream = new DataInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream());
       String message  = input_stream.readUTF();

       someMethod();           //This method can generate an exception, then the application closes and I can not receive new requests
       text.append("\n" + message);
       mySocket.close();
   } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

Then you'll log the exception and just carry on.

PS: There are probably some exceptions that mean that retries are futile and you need to abandon the process rather than fill the log with a zillion severe errors.

I recommend reading the documentation and devising a slightly more mature error handling strategy than 'ignore everything and soldier on'.

Answer (score 2):

A try-catch does not have to go around all your code at once. The one you have around your whole `run` method is very useful to log errors that are truly fatal. You can have another one around `someMethod();` to prevent those exceptions from breaking the loop:

```
try {
    someMethod();
} catch(ZeroDivisionException e) {
    // handle the exception
} catch(SomeOtherException e) {
    // handle the other exception
}
```

The exceptions here are made up, but I'm sure you get the idea. How you handle them is up to you. As long as you don't re-throw any of them, the loop won't end and your outer block won't be triggered.

You can nest catch blocks pretty much however you like, so you can catch `IOException` in the inner block as well as the outer one. The outer block will still clean up for the errors you can't control.